# Guidelines in What is a Word™? questions

Tags: discussion

I'm sure we all know of the latest puzzle craze; the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) or [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) which has been revived from the embers mainly thanks to the efforts of [Engineer Toast](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9000/engineer-toast).

I genuinely love these puzzles, and have even [participated myself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42393/what-is-a-veteran-word).

However I feel that because these puzzles have become so popular, I feel there needs to be *some* sort of.... guidelines.

While the majority of these puzzles are good quality, there have been [some](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42556/what-is-a-refreshing-word) which aren't quite as good - no offence intended

I feel the question that needs to be asked is:

### How many examples should be required?

Comment: I think there should a be special tag for these kinds of puzzles first. Giving them specific guidelines means we treat them to be a kind or form of puzzle that other puzzles are not. See [the relevant meta thread.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/what-is-a-puzzle-tag?rq=1)

Comment: It's worth noting that this type of puzzle was NOT, as I thought when writing the above-linked meta question, invented by JLee: see [these earlier examples](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=company+of+thirteen). I'm about to create the tag now, but I'll have to change the tag wiki from what I originally proposed.

Comment: Those earlier "Company of Thirteen" examples have the crucial difference that they give no non-examples, so they have the drawback that, if the solver thinks of a property which is in fact too wide, the puzzle gives no clue that this property is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that we need "rules" for this type of puzzle any more than we do for any other type of puzzle on this website.  Yes, there have been a few sub-standard examples of this type of puzzle.  ***That is why we have downvotes.*** It looks like were employed quite effectually with that example, as it is currently at a score of **-8**.

Any type of puzzle will have the occasional bad egg.  I would argue that this particular type has actually had mostly very good puzzles, with very few exceptions.  I chalk that up to the rigour employed by JLee when they first created this puzzle type.

So I don't think anything needs to be done.  The bad eggs will fall victim to the community scoring system, just as happens with any other type of puzzle.

Comment: Do you not think we need a certain amount of examples?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yes, in order for the question not to be considered *too broad*, there should be a decent amount of examples.  But I don't think we need to prescribe a specific number of examples any more than we prescribe the number of lines in a riddle.  It's sufficient to say, "There must be a decent number of examples," and if there aren't and it allows for multiple feasible answers, then the question will probably be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: Fair enough, can't argue with you there.

Comment: "*I don't think that we need "rules" for this type of puzzle any more than we do for any other type of puzzle on this website.*" - ahem, it's not so long since there was a rule that a certain type of puzzle had to go through a sandbox before being posted :-) Also, [JLee didn't actually create this puzzle type](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/another-company-of-thirteen).

Comment: @randal'thor ...and pretty much everyone agrees that that "rule" was a bad idea. Hopefully we've learned from that experience. (Also, I hope you're aware that the question you linked was based on another earlier one.) But JLee did create the particular brand and formatting of these puzzles.

Comment: Yes, I saw that Moghwyn created the first one, but for maximum irony I wanted to link to the one that you yourself made :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### My Suggested Guideline

1. There should be at least $10$ examples

That way there won't be any doubt over the 'rule', or there won't be multiple rules

Comment: What do you mean by "solvable by just looking at the words"? If you know what to look for, a lot of rules are solvable by just looking.

Comment: @Deusovi, I'm trying to think of a way of saying 'not easy' but is something you can follow. Any help?

Comment: Vulgar?? Did someone make a rule that *was* vulgar?

Comment: @randal'thor Take a look at the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be also required that the logics in these puzzles do not repeat. I'm pretty sure there are already a few puzzles in which the words contain letters from one set of words or another, and I believe spending time just to discover that the puzzle does not contain any new ideas, is not that great.

Comment: +1, but: in order to ensure this, anyone posting a new Word™ puzzle would have to check all the previous ones to see what the method of solution was, which would be quite time-consuming. Also, if the solutions are *exactly* identical we can close as duplicate.